# HTML Button inside SVG document

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I have following problem I want to dynamically create HTML buttons inside SVG document. At first I look over the SVG document, find apropriate reactangle and replace rectangle with `<foreignObject>`element. I am able to generate following SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   viewBox="0 0 93.875076 43.283451"
   id="svg20755"
   xml:space="preserve">

    <g id="Button-1" transform="translate(0.5000775,0.50220189)">

       <foreignObject xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="93" height="43">
           <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="margin: 0px; height: 100%;">
            <button type="button" style="width:100%; height:100%;" onclick="alert('Button clicked')">
                Juhuhuhu!
            </button>
           </body>
       </foreignObject>

    </g>
</svg>
```

This is the snippet how I create the element

```
var ns_HTML = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
var ns_SVG = REX.HELPERS.ns_svg;

var element = <Some code to load an SVG element>

var foreignObject = document.createElementNS(ns_SVG, 'foreignObject');

var body = document.createElementNS(ns_HTML, 'body');
body.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'); // FF
body.style.margin = '0px';
body.style.height = '100%';        

var button = document.createElementNS(ns_HTML, 'button');    
button.setAttribute('type','button');    
button.setAttribute('style','width:100%; height:100%;');
button.innerHTML = 'Test!';

body.appendChild(button);
foreignObject.appendChild(body);
```

I have two problems especially in Chrome Browser:

1. The element `<body>` did not fill the height of the `<foreignObject>`
2. <strike>The `button` did not behave as a button (no reaction on mouseover and mousedown)</strike> (It seems that this was fixed in new release of Chrome and Firefox)

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RCbh2/)

Comment: FYI, I tried to add an explicit `-webkit-appearance: button` to the `@style`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: similarly `appearance: push-button;` doesnt work

Comment: Thanks to this question. It is the first question that I read concerning SVG file containing HMTL elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you say `<body>` element doesn't fill the height of `<foreignObject>` !?

When I try now in 2020, I see only a button in midlle on screen.

I have added a SVG `<rect>` element with same size (width and height) than `<foreignObject>` to have the possibility to compare these 2 objects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="2.0"
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  viewBox="0 0 90 50"
  >

<g transform="translate(1 0)">
    <foreignObject xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="20">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="margin:0px; height:100%;">
            <button type="button" style="width:100%; height:100%;" onclick="alert('Button clicked')">
            Juhuhuhu!
            </button>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
    <rect x="0" y="25" width="80" height="20" stroke="orange" stroke-width="2" fill="white"/>
</g>
```

As you can see, they have same size !

[image]

I put an image to proove what I say because it is possible that in 1 year what I have written is false !

Comment: It seems that browsers somehow start support of this feature. But still I found out that this doesn't work for Safari on iOS. So I abandoned this approach long time ago.